# Scoping of keys in vscode extension global scope

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The context of a vscode extension provides access to [globalState](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext) which is a [Memento](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Memento) object with key/value pairs. My question is: does each extension get its own memento object, or is there one shared by all extensions? Just wondering whether I need to make my keys more specific (e.g., `my.extension.foo`), or if I can keep the keys simple (e.g., `foo`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's scoped to your extension, so you can keep them simple:

> However, when an extension uses storage, it will always get it's data stored under 1 key (the extension name + extension ID). We never allow to write directly into storage under a key that could conflict with other keys.

([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87110#issuecomment-566400914))

Comment: is there a way to find and loop through all stored keys of an extension? I wanted to delete unused old keys

Comment: Not that I'm aware.