# How to get data saved by vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to know how to retrieve the data from an extension I installed on my vscode (I did not write the extension). This is to export this data to another computer.

I know that the extension use `context.globalState` to store the data.

Thank you for your answer

Comment: The state is scoped to the extension. There's no API for other extensions to retrieve it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341372/scoping-of-keys-in-vscode-extension-global-scope/62341874#62341874.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way to retrieve the data not by another extension but by the user ?